# Calculating log returns using R

Tags: r, returns

I am trying to calculate the log returns of a dataset in R using the usual log differencing method. However, the calculated data is simply a vector of zeroes. I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the snippet showing what I'm doing

```
> prices <- data$cl
> head(prices)
[1] 1108.1 1095.4 1095.4 1102.2 1096.3 1096.7
>
>
> lrets <- log(lag(prices)) - log(prices)
> head(lrets)
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0
> summary(lrets)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
      0       0       0       0       0       0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: lrets <- diff(log(prices))

Comment: @VishalBelsare you should add that as an answer.

Comment: @Patrick Burns, vonjd, aajajim thanks to all of you for answering. I learned new information.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are simply doing $log(S_t) - log(S_t) = 0$ for all $t$. Instead, try

```
> n <- length(prices);
> lrest <- log(prices[-1]/prices[-n])
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Or the more traditional, fewer characters: diff(log(prices)) which also works when 'prices' is a matrix with times in the rows and assets in the columns.  The other lesson is that 'lag' doesn't do what we naively expect it to do.

Comment: To be sure that `lag` works as you expect, it is much safer to store your time series as `zoo` or `xts` objects: if you use vectors (or even `ts` objects), many operations will discard or ignore the timestamps.

Comment: hadnt noticed the "diff" function yet. A handy one, indeed.

Comment: @PatrickBurns: +1 for your input. I preferred your more succinct syntax. Would have accepted that as an answer.

Comment: i have been using diff(log(prices)) for a while, but was starting to doubt as it seems almost noone use it. thanks :)

Comment: There was a slight (obvious?) error in my reply with taking the negative logreturn instead. Now corrected. Thanks to user6569 that notified me.

Answer (score 9):

An easy way to perform what you need is do it this way:

if your data are daily then :

```
> prices <- data$cl
> log_returns <- diff(log(prices), lag=1)
```

would provide you with daily log returns, if you change the $lag=1$ to $lag=5$ then you will get weekly moving log returns.

Comment: While I have some experience in finance, I'm new to R (and this site).  Question on this post, @aajajim: your suggestion looks very appealing, but another commenter suggests working in zoo, with which I am familiar. Since zoo allows for an irregular times series, how does your answer change if using zoo?

Comment: Doesn't change at all, it's still the same code. At least for my zoo object the function he posted worked without any flaws.

Answer (score 7):

I think the simplest method for calculating log returns is `ROC` from the `TTR` package:

```
> data(ttrc)
> roc <- ROC(ttrc[,"Close"])
```

https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=TTR

Answer (score 2):

just to add another method:

```
>lrtn=diff(log(prices))
```

for daily log returns, if you have daily prices.

Answer (score 1):

This is inelegant, but is effective and will do the job.

```
prices<-c(1108.1,1095.4,1095.4,1102.2,1096.3,1096.7)
n<-length(prices)
lrets<-log(prices[2:n])-log(prices[1:(n-1)])
print(lrets)
summary(lrets)
```

Please note that it is possible to compress this even further, but with a loss of readability.

Also note, that you can sometimes get zeros because the number of significant digits you have set as your default is too few.

The argument *against* using this happens when you want to control an arbitrary number of lags.  Manually slicing data as in the above could cause you to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get rid of the first NA produced you can either start at 0 or omit the first row like this:

```
require(quantmod)
getSymbols("MSFT")
MSFT$Log_Returns <- diff(log(MSFT$Adjusted)); MSFT$Log_Returns[1] <- 0 # this will make the first row of your returns series equal 0, which arguably is correct for any starting date.

MSFT$Log_Returns <- diff(log(MSFT$Adjusted))
MSFT <- MSFT[2:nrow(MSFT),] # this option will remove the first row which is a NA and therefore not introduce a 0.
```

Both options work fine, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is simplest with tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>% 
mutate(across(stock_1:stock_n, ~ log(.x))) %>% 
    mutate(across(stock_1:stock_n)-lag(across(stock_1:stock_n)))
```

Regards.